# Finding the longest sequence of dates in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'd like to know how to find the longest unbroken sequence of dates (formatted as `2016-11-27`) in a `publish_date` column (dates are not the index, though I suppose they could be).

There are a number of stack overflow questions which are similar, but AFAICT all proposed answers return the *size* of the longest sequence, which is not what I'm after.

I want to know e.g. that the stretch from `2017-01-01` to `2017-06-01` had no missing dates and was the longest such streak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# initialize data
data = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
        'date': ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-09', '2017-01-31']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# create mask that indicates sequential pair of days (except the first date)
df['mask'] = 1
df.loc[df['date'] - datetime.timedelta(days=1) == df['date'].shift(),'mask'] = 0

# convert mask to numbers - each sequence have its own number
df['mask'] = df['mask'].cumsum()

# find largest sequence number and get this sequence
res = df.loc[df['mask'] == df['mask'].value_counts().idxmax(), 'date']

# extract min and max dates if you need
min_date = res.min()
max_date = res.max()

# print result
print('min_date: {}'.format(min_date))
print('max_date: {}'.format(max_date))
print('result:')
print(res)
```

The result will be:

```
min_date: 2017-01-05 00:00:00
max_date: 2017-01-07 00:00:00
result:
2   2017-01-05
3   2017-01-06
4   2017-01-07
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'd upvote but I don't have the reputation required.

Comment: You are welcome! You can mark the answer as correct - it is better than upvote ;)